# Koala gem get_object returns GraphMethodException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm using the Koala gem to get metrics (likes, comments, and shares) on Facebook posts. I literally have not touched the Koala code in  months, yet is suddenly stopped working. I'm able to get likes and comments, but not shares. I checked the docs for the gem as well as the issues on GitHub and didn't see anything related to my issue. Not sure if it's my code or the gem or a change to Facebook's API.

I have the following method, which is called by another method, which is responsible for updating all metrics on the post.

```
def call_facebook_api(client, method, pid, metric)
    resp = client.method(method).call(pid, metric)
rescue Koala::Facebook::ClientError => e
    puts "Rescue from #{e}"
    puts "Method: #{method}"
    puts "Metric: #{metric}"
    puts "Post ID: #{pid}"
    return nil
end
```

Here are some sample values for the method arguments:

```
client
=> #<Koala::Facebook::API:0x007fbbfdf25dd0 @access_token="super_secret",@app_secret="super_duper_secret">
method
=> :get_object
pid
=> "202001613484188_1142111705834093"
metric
=> {:fields=>["shares"]}
```

When I run the method above with these inputs it returns this error:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api [HTTP 400]
from /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/koala-2.2.0/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:515:in `block in graph_call'
```

I've also tried the following combinations unsuccessfully:

```
client.get_object(pid)
client.get_object(pid, fields: ['shares'])
client.get_object(pid, 'shares')
client.get_object("#{pid}/sharedposts")
client.get_object("#{pid}?fields=sharedposts")
client.get_object("#{pid}?fields=shared")
client.get_object("#{pid}?fields=shares")
client.get_connections(pid)
client.get_connections(pid, 'shares')
client.get_connections("#{pid}/sharedposts")
```

Referencing the Graph API docs hasn't given me any new insights into the problem.

As I said before, I haven't touched the above code in months, yet it only recently stopped working. I did recently upgrade my Rails app from 4.06 to 4.2.5.1. I also upgraded from Ruby 2.0.0 to 2.3.0. I did not upgrade the Koala gem though. I was already running 2.2.0 (latest).

Comment: “Unsupported GET request” means that either the object you are trying to read doesn’t exist – or you do not have the right to see it with the access token you are using and the permissions it includes.

Comment: My access token is valid and has the correct permissions and I can confirm that the object does exist by visiting the post url, which includes the post id.

Comment: Which permissions are those, and who “owns” the post?

Comment: I own the post. It's public. The permissions are public_profile, manage_pages, publish_pages, and read_insights.